# Using scipy optimizer with a pandas DataFrame objective function

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, scipy-optimize

I am trying to create an optimizer that better fits the moving average with the time series data by shifting it backwards, but I am running into them problem:

```
only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index.
```

My *objective function* to minimize is:

```
def mse(shift, prices, d=5):
    ma = prices.rolling(d).mean().shift(-shift)
    return ((prices - ma)**2).sum()
```

and the *optimizer function* is:

```
def reduce_MSE(prices: pd.Series, d: int) -> int:
    init_value = 1
    shift = minimize(mse, x0=init_value, args=(prices,d), options={'maxiter':10000}, bounds=((0.0, 10.0),))
    return shift
```

I tried changing the objective function and saw the the line of code responsible for the error is

```
ma = prices.rolling(d).mean().shift(-shift)
```

The optimizer worked fine if I removed this part of code. Also, my `mse` objective function works if I use it outside the optimizer.

My question is if it is not possible to use some pandas functions as objective functions for the optimizer or if I am doing it the wrong way.

Thanks

Comment: Pandas `shift()` method only accepts integer-valued arguments while scipy.optimize.minimize is an interface for *continuous* optimization problems, i.e. the optimization variables are floats. Thus, this won't work. You probably rather want to formulate this problem as a mixed-integer optimization problem and solve it.

Comment: Further to @joni comment there are several scipy minimisers that can work with integrality constraints, e.g. [differential_evolution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html) has the `integrality` keyword.